# excel send email macro in userform

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have the following logic to send an email through outlook from excel. using a userform. The problem is having the textbox activated upon selecting the checkbox. The texbox does not activate upon checking it. I also have tried with the visible property.

The problem is the checkbox is not activating the logic that the else statement.

```
Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
On Error GoTo ERRORMSG
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim olInsp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object


Set otlApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olMail = otlApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set Doc = olMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
Set mainWB = ActiveWorkbook

If CheckBox1.Value = False Then

mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("m8").Value = ComboBox4.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("n8").Value = TextBox40.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("q8").Value = ComboBox5.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("r8").Value = ComboBox6.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("s8").Value = ComboBox7.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("t8").Value = TextBox44.Value


 On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("G12").Value"
    .cc = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("L12").Value
    .Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("O15").Value
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range

    'force html format
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
    .display


    '--- start with 6 CrLf's, so we can place each table
    '    above all but the last used...
    oRng.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
    '    and back up one character (so that the table inserts before the SIXTH CrLf)
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    oRng.collapse 0
    oRng.Move 1, -1
    Range("K3:T10").Select
    Selection.Copy
    oRng.Paste


    '--- finally move the cursor all the way to the end and paste the
    '    second table BELOW the SIXTH CrLf
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    oRng.collapse 0
    Range("K38:T46").Select
    Selection.Copy
    oRng.Paste
End With

Else
Label54.enable = True
TextBox46.enable = True

mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("m57").Value = ComboBox4.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("n57").Value = TextBox40.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("O57").Value = TextBox46.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("q57").Value = ComboBox5.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("r57").Value = ComboBox6.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("s57").Value = ComboBox7.Value
mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("t57").Value = TextBox44.Value


 On Error Resume Next
Set OutApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
If Err <> 0 Then Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

With OutMail
    .To = "mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("G12").Value"
    .cc = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("L12").Value
    .Subject = mainWB.Sheets("Mail").Range("O15").Value
    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range

    'force html format
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
    .display


    '--- start with 6 CrLf's, so we can place each table
    '    above all but the last used...
    oRng.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

    '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
    '    and back up one character (so that the table inserts before the SIXTH CrLf)
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    oRng.collapse 0
    oRng.Move 1, -1
    Range("K52:T59").Select
    Selection.Copy
    oRng.Paste


    '--- finally move the cursor all the way to the end and paste the
    '    second table BELOW the SIXTH CrLf
    Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
    oRng.collapse 0
    Range("K38:T46").Select
    Selection.Copy
    oRng.Paste
End With
End If
Exit Sub
ERRORMSG:
MsgBox "No email was sent", vbExclamation
End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by the textbox does not active upon checking it? Do you want to set the focus to the textbox?

Comment: `Label54.enable = True TextBox46.enable = True` is initially set to enable false. Then I implemented the logic with checkbox to activate the label and the texbox upon the checking the box, but it does not do anything. I did not set the focus on anything. I do not want the focus to set on anything.

Comment: Alright, the proper setting is `TextBox46.Enabled = True` instead of `TextBox46.Enable = True`

Comment: yeah. Thanks for catching up on that. I did correct it. It still doesnt enable  the checkobx to enter data

Comment: You want the `Textbox` to be enabled after clicking the `Checkbox` but the specific code is in the `commandbutton_Click()` event. You will need to place it in the `Checkbox_Exit()` event.

Answer (score 0):

you must:

- set both `Label54` and `TextBox46` `Enabled` property prior to executing any Userform event handling code

  this you can achieve:

  - either with a `Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()` sub:

    ```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
        With Me
            .Label54.Enabled = False
            .TextBox46.Enabled = False
        End With
    End Sub
    ```
  - or in the Userform calling block of your "main" sub

    ```
    Sub Main()

        ... code

        With MyUserForm '<--| change "MyUserForm" to your actual userform name
            .Label54.Enabled = False
            .TextBox46.Enabled = False

            ... other possible code here to set some Userform members before showing it

            .Show '<--| show your userform
        End With
        Unload MyUserForm

        ... more code

    End SUb
    ```
- set both `Label54` and `TextBox46` `Enabled` property in your `CommandButton9_Click` event handler accordingly to `CheckBox1` value

  like follows:

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Private Sub CommandButton9_Click()
      Dim OutApp As Object
      Dim mailSht As Worksheet
      Dim rowOffset As Long

      Set OutApp = GetApp("Outlook.Application")
      If OutApp Is Nothing Then
          MsgBox "Couldn't set 'Outlook.Application' object"
          Exit Sub
      End If

      Set mailSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Mail")
      rowOffset = IIf(CheckBox1, 56, 7) '<--| set a row offset (from row 1) in according to CheckBox value

      Label54.Enabled = CheckBox1 '<--| enable Label54 control if CheckBox1 is checked
      TextBox46.Enabled = CheckBox1 '<--| enable TextBox46 control if CheckBox1 is checked

      With Me '<--| refer to this userform
          'fill "Mail" sheet properly offsetted cells with ComboBoxes and TextBoxes values
          FillRangeWithComboBoxValue .ComboBox4, mailSht.Range("m1").Offset(rowOffset)
          mailSht.Range("n1").Offset(rowOffset).value = .TextBox40.value
          FillRangeWithComboBoxValue .ComboBox5, mailSht.Range("q1").Offset(rowOffset)
          FillRangeWithComboBoxValue .ComboBox6, mailSht.Range("r1").Offset(rowOffset)
          FillRangeWithComboBoxValue .ComboBox7, mailSht.Range("s1").Offset(rowOffset)
          mailSht.Range("t1").Offset(rowOffset).value = .TextBox44.value
      End With

      On Error GoTo ERRORMSG
      With OutApp.CreateItem(0)
          .To = mailSht.Range("G12").value
          .CC = mailSht.Range("L12").value
          .Subject = mailSht.Range("O15").value

          'force html format
          .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><body></HTML>"
          .display
          With .GetInspector.WordEditor
              '--- start with 6 CrLf's, so we can place each table
              '    above all but the last used...
              .Range.InsertAfter vbCrLf & vbCrLf

              '--- now reselect the entire document, collapse our cursor to the end
              '    and back up one character (so that the table inserts before the SIXTH CrLf)
              With .Range
                  .collapse 0
                  .Move 1, -1
                  mailSht.Range("K3:T10").Copy
                  .Paste
              End With

              '--- finally move the cursor all the way to the end and paste the
              '    second table BELOW the SIXTH CrLf
              With .Range
                  .collapse 0
                  mailSht.Range("K38:T46").Copy
                  .Paste
              End With
          End With
      End With
      Set OutApp = Nothing '<--| dispose the object variable

      Exit Sub
  ERRORMSG:
      MsgBox "Error on email processing", vbExclamation
  End Sub

  Function GetApp(appName As String) As Object
      On Error Resume Next
      Set GetApp = GetObject(, appName)
      If GetApp Is Nothing Then Set GetApp = CreateObject(appName)
  End Function

  Sub FillRangeWithComboBoxValue(cb As msforms.ComboBox, rng As Range)
      If cb.ListIndex <> -1 Then rng.value = cb.value
  End Sub
  ```

  where you see I proposed some code shortening and *modulizing* tips to have it (hopefully) more readable and maintainable

Comment: Would the _brave_ downvoter show up and give any explanation so as to both have people know why they shouldn't follow thi answer and teach me how to improve it?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys, it was a simple fix. I put the checkbox condition in the checkbox change event and it works like a gem.

`Private Sub CheckBox1_Change()`

Comment: Fine. However you may want to consider code refactoring I proposed to you

Comment: Thanks a ton, I will be looking into this. The code modulizing is amazing. But it would take a while, as I have multiple codes in the userform.

Comment: then you may want to post it in [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vba) and have people help you in increasing your code quality and (possibily) performance